# TestCases is not passing, while the console.log's are correct

Tags: javascript

The problem is below

```
/* Write a program to build a `Pyramid of stars` of given height */

const buildPyramid = () => {
    // Write your code here
};

/* For example,
INPUT - buildPyramid(6)
OUTPUT -
     *
    * *
   * * *
  * * * *
 * * * * *
* * * * * *

*/

module.exports = buildPyramid;
```

I added the code to get the desired pattern as below

```
const buildPyramid = (n) => {
        var output;
    if(Number.isInteger(n)){
        for(var i=1; i<= n; i++){      
            var output =  ' '.repeat(n-i)+'* '.repeat(i)+' '.repeat(n-i);  
            console.log(output);
            return output;         
       }

    }else{
        console.log('Not a number');
        return '';
    }   
};

module.exports = buildPyramid;
```

This is the test cases provided

```
const chai = require('chai');
const expect = chai.expect;
const pyramid = require('../solutions/q1_pyramid_of_stars.js');

describe('Testing - pyramid_of_stars', () => {
    it('module return type test case', (done) => {
        expect(typeof pyramid).to.deep.equal('function');
        done();
    });

    it('positive test case for odd count of height', (done) => {
        expect(pyramid(5)).equal(
            '     *  \n    * *  \n   * * *  \n  * * * *  \n * * * * *  \n');
        done();
    });

    it('positive test case for even count of height', (done) => {
        expect(pyramid(6)).equal(
            '      *  \n     * *  \n    * * *  \n   * * * *  \n  * * * * *  \n * * * * * *  \n');
        done();
    });

    it('negative test case', (done) => {
        expect(pyramid('invalid value')).to.deep.equal('');
        done();
    });
});
```

But I'm missing something, due to which, all the test cases are failed, as I think, I'm not passing the resultant output, can you help me what is that I'm missing

```
Testing - pyramid_of_stars
    √ module return type test case
    *
    1) positive test case for odd count of height
     *
    2) positive test case for even count of height
Not a number
    √ negative test case


  2 passing (22ms)
  2 failing

  1) Testing - pyramid_of_stars
       positive test case for odd count of height:

      AssertionError: expected ....
      + expected - actual

      -    *     
      +     *  
      +    * *  
      +   * * *  

      at Context.it (test\q1_pyramid_of_stars.spec.js:12:22)

  2) Testing - pyramid_of_stars
       positive test case for even count of height:

      AssertionError: expected ' ...
      + expected - actual

      -     *      
      +      *  
      +     * * 

      at Context.it (test\q1_pyramid_of_stars.spec.js:18:22)
```

when I run the code setting the value on n as local variable, it is getting desired output.

Comment: But you never take `n`? I am not convinced this function works at all.

Comment: You also don't return anything from the function.

Comment: You forgot to pass a parameter in you fonction, you n is declared locally so it all always go in the else

Comment: just updated the code with return in it and the updated output

Comment: You still never take input. And once you do, you are not generating the output to have newlines, either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You're returning from a *for* loop, which is not required**

As you can see from your output:

```
 + expected - actual

      -    *     
      +     *  
      +    * *  
      +   * * *
```

Only the first row is what you actually *return*

This is because of your for loop:

```
for(var i=1; i<= n; i++){      
    var output =  ' '.repeat(n-i)+'* '.repeat(i)+' '.repeat(n-i);  
    console.log(output);
    return output;         
}
```

Your for loop is not a function, so when you return, it returns from buildPyramid.

Either your test needs to mock the console.log, or build up the string. Here are two options for building up th string:

(old way)

```js
function buildPyramid(n) {
  // create a variable outside of the for loop
  let pyramid = '';
  for (var i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    var output = ' '.repeat(n - i) + '* '.repeat(i) + ' '.repeat(n - i);
    console.log(output);
    //update outer variable
    pyramid += `\n ${output}`;
  }
  // return it after the for loop is finished
  return pyramid;
}

console.log(buildPyramid(6))
```

(modern way)

```js
const pyramidLevel = (level, totalLevels) => ' '.repeat(totalLevels - level) + '* '.repeat(level) + ' '.repeat(totalLevels - level)

// reduce an array of size n
const pyramid = n => Array.from(Array(n))
  .reduce((pyramid, value, level) => {
    // for each element in the initial array
    // append the new pyramid level to your previous state
    pyramid += `\n ${pyramidLevel(level, n+1)}`;
    return pyramid;
    // the last argument of reduce is your 'initial' state
  }, '')

console.log(pyramid(6));
```

Either way works but I prefer the modern way for various reasons, mainly that you don't need a variable to exist out side of the main scope you care about.